# AngularJS and Angular-Snap : Snap constructor is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, snap.js

"Make sure window.Snap is defined or supply your own with SnapConstructorProvider.use(MySnap)."

That's what I have when I'm trying to use angular-snap. I followed what they said in github but still didn't work. Can I have some help ? I watched the angular-snap code and I saw a test :

```
if(angular.isUndefined(S)) {
      throw new Error('Snap constructor is not defined. Make sure ' +
          'window.Snap is defined or supply your own with ' +
          'SnapConstructorProvider.use(MySnap).');
    }
```

When I put a console.log of angular.isUndefined, it returns true but I don't know why.

Here the html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>AO</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/angular-snap.min.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

  <snap-drawer>
    <p>I'm a drawer ! I maybe I've got some sweet navigation links.</p>
  </snap-drawer>

  <snap-content>
    <p>Hello! I'm your main content!</p>
  </snap-content>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/snap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-snap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['snap']);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should rather ask the question in the Angular-Snap github project, so the auther will see whether it's a bug or not.

Comment: I've post this on Github, thanks for your answer !

Comment: Are there any other errors reported in the console? Are you sure the `snap.js` file is loading alright (i.e. not a 404). If both of those check out maybe you could post a jsbin or plunkr demonstrating the issue? It looks like you're at least attempting to include the right things in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include snap.js library to your index.html page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.js/1.9.3/snap.min.js"></script>
```